# I accidentally closed the debug result visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Hi guys i need your help I accidentally closed the debug window at the bottom part of the screen in visual studio 2010. Please help me I could not find it anymore :( thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is it the `Debug > Windows > Output` (in the main menu) window that you are looking for?

Comment: View / Window menu?  Sorry - it's been too long since I've worked with Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you mean the Immediate Window?
`Debug > Windows > Immediate Window`
Or press `Ctrl + Alt + I`.

Comment: Thanks guys found it already :)

Answer (score 1):

You can open it again using the menu bar : you choose `Debug`, then `Windows` submenu and click on `Output`.

It should open again the panel you just closed.

Answer (score 0):

I just clicked the view menu as what @Kieveli has said and click the error list in there and it also has a shortcut key of `Ctrl +\,E` .